# App displaying default ICON in BBM connected apps list

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades, bb-messenger

I am working on BB10 app which has BBM functionality.

I have registered with BBM, but when I see BBM connected apps list App is displaying with default App icon.How can I change default app icon to my own app Icon.

Please Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

It should use your application icon.  However, there is an issue where if you change your application icon it doesn't pick up the change.  So if you installed the application once with the default icon, it would remain that way on that device.  The issue is logged here:

[ProfileBox icon not updated when application upgraded with new icon](https://www.blackberry.com/jira/browse/BBTEN-970)